# Re-Prompt user after invalid input for multiple for loops

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java so please be patient and do not judgement for lack of researched. Here me out

This program is basic calculated program. It design for user to calculate the total cost of the project.

My program debug fine but the problem is when the user type invalid entry.
Once the user type invalid entry, the for loop just end after `Please, enter the amount!`

I want the program to keep the for loop going until the user type a valid entry.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class icalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double cost, percentage;
        int years;


        System.out.println("What the estimate cost of the project?");
        cost = Keyboard.nextDouble();

        if (cost <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please, enter the amount!");
        } else if(cost > 0) {

            System.out.println("What the estimate percentage cost of the project?   ");
            percentage = Keyboard.nextDouble();

            if (percentage <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Please, enter the amount!");
            } else if(percentage > 0) {

                System.out.println("How long it will take to complete the project? \n"
                        + "Please, enter whole numbers.");
                years = Keyboard.nextInt();

                if (years <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please, enter the amount!");
                } else if (years > 0) {
```

This part is the calculation area:

```
double c = cost;
                        double p = percentage;
                        int y = years;

                        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
                            c = Math.round(((p/100) * c) + y);
                            System.out.println("At  " + percentage + "% rate, the cost of the project will be $"
                                    + c + " which take " + years + " years to be complete");
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I was thinking if the do while loop would be better but I am not trying to make the program more complaicated then what it is.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem is that you're describing/observing.  Can you be specific?

Comment: @David  When I run the program, if a user type invalid entry the program will reply `Please, enter the amount!` then the program end. I want the program to keep going the for loop until the user type a valid entry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a more "official" term for the concept, but it sounds like for any given user input you want to have an "input loop" until a valid value is provided.  (Whereas currently the code has no way of "returning to the prompt" and when the `if` to check for a valid value isn't satisfied the logic simply concludes.)

For each input, it might look something like this:

```
double cost = 0;
while (cost <= 0) {
    System.out.println("What the estimate cost of the project?");
    cost = Keyboard.nextDouble();

    if (cost <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Please, enter the amount!");
    }
}
```

There are undoubtedly a variety of ways to structure it, but the concept is the same.  Declare the variable to an initial (business-invalid) value, repeat prompting the user until the value is business-valid, so after the loop you know that you have a valid value.

You can further direct your learning/practice with something like this by encapsulating this process into its own method, a method which returns the value you want from the user.  Your `main()` method would call the other method to get the value.  After encapsulating this for each input, note the similarities and see if you can refactor the encapsulated operation into a *single* method instead of a separate one for each input.  (Remember to name things clearly and appropriately.  Change the names if the meaning changes after a refactoring.)

Ultimately an ideal structure would be to get away from these nested brackets (`if`s within loops within `if`s, etc. all pushing to the right) and instead have a simple set of well-named method calls which themselves describe the overall operation being performed.